# Update Items In View Controller After Selecting Cell in UITableView

Tags: swift

I am trying to update various labels and text fields in my View Controller based upon what the user selects in the TableView

I'm using Swift 4.2 with a TableView in a regular View Controller, not a TableViewController, and have looked all over these forums and others using various functions to get check if a cell is selected, and then do something based on each cell that is selected

This is the function that I keep seeing in forums, and it doesn't seem to be doing anything, as the label I am trying to change does not change based on what cell is selected:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    whichGPULbl.text = "\(gpuList[indexPath.row])"
}
```

As a note: gpuList is the array that the TableView uses for its content

So if in the TableView, the cell "GTX 1070" is selected, the label "whichGPULbl" should display "GTX 1070", and then update any time the user selects a new cell

Answer (score 0):

If setup is correct then you miss

```
tableView.delegate = self
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I had this in my viewDidLoad() at some point, but I must've deleted it by mistake. Thanks again

Comment: I tried this, however I was receiving an error saying that I can't assign ViewController to "UITableViewDelegate", so I added "UITableViewDelegate" to the class header, and while the error went away, I received a SIGABRT error in the "@UIApplicationMain" section. I am fairly new to swift, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong here

Comment: After some more tinkering, I realized I was also missing "tableView.dataSource = self", and the class header that goes with it, so after applying an automatic fix to make one of the tableView functions "internal", everything worked